Doubts about time integration and orthogonality of Floquet states
This question pertains to the content of paper about the Floquet theory. To clarify the core issue, I will discuss the problem using a simplified setting.
In Floquet theory, the solution of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for a quantum system with a periodic Hamiltonian $H(t+T) = H(t)$ is described using Floquet states. The Floquet states are given by:
\begin{equation}
    |\psi_m(t)\rangle = e^{-i \epsilon_m t} |u_m(t)\rangle
\end{equation}
where $|u_m(t)\rangle$ is a periodic state with the period $T$, and $\epsilon_m$ is called the quasienergy. The index $m$ distinguishes different Floquet states for a given quasienergy. Furthermore, each Floquet state can have replicas, indexed by an integer $l \in \mathbb{Z}$, corresponding to different Fourier components. These are described by the state:
\begin{equation}
    |u_{\alpha}(t)\rangle = e^{il\omega t}|u_m(t)\rangle
\end{equation}
where $\alpha = (m, l)$ is a double index, and $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$ is the angular frequency associated with the period $T$. From the orthogonality and completeness of the Floquet states, the following completeness relation holds:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T dt \, \langle u_{\alpha}(t) | u_{\beta}(t) \rangle = \delta_{\alpha\beta}
\end{equation}
Using the orthogonality of the Floquet states $|u_{\alpha}(t)\rangle$ (with $\alpha = (m, l)$), I tried to derive the time evolution equation as follows.
The solution of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation was expanded in terms of the Floquet states, leading to the following equation:
\begin{equation}
    |\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}(t) |u_{\alpha}(t)\rangle
\end{equation}
This was then substituted into the time-dependent Schrödinger equation:
\begin{equation}
    i \frac{d}{dt} |\psi(t)\rangle = H(t) |\psi(t)\rangle
\end{equation}
Both sides were multiplied by the Floquet state $\langle u_{\beta}(t) |$ and integrated over one period $T$:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T dt \, \langle u_{\beta}(t)| \left[ i \sum_{\alpha} \left( \frac{dc_{\alpha}(t)}{dt} |u_{\alpha}(t)\rangle + c_{\alpha}(t) \frac{d}{dt} |u_{\alpha}(t)\rangle \right) \right] = \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T dt \, \langle u_{\beta}(t)| \left[ \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}(t) \epsilon_{\alpha} |u_{\alpha}(t)\rangle \right]
\end{equation}
This was then transformed into:
\begin{equation}
    i \frac{dc_{\beta}(t)}{dt} + i \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha}(t) \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T dt \, \langle u_{\beta}(t)| \frac{d}{dt} |u_{\alpha}(t)\rangle = \epsilon_{\beta} c_{\beta}(t)
\end{equation}
In the above transformation, I believe it is impossible to obtain the Kronecker delta $\delta_{\alpha\beta}$ through time integration because the expansion coefficients $c_{\alpha}(t)$ are included in the integrand. While the orthogonality of the Floquet states is obtained through integration over one period, we cannot ignore the time dependence of the expansion coefficients $c_{\alpha}(t)$.
However, the results in the paper and the numerical calculations are consistent, so I suspect there is something I am misunderstanding. What could be the issue here?

Either the states or the coefficients should be independent of time.
